# "Supply and demand" is popular or a singular when use as a concept?

Tags: grammar

> Supply and demand is perhaps one of the most fundamental concepts of economics.

from https://www.investopedia.com/university/economics/economics3.asp

Should not we say "Supply and demand are ..." or "'supply and demand' is ..."?

Comment: The full name is "The law of supply and demand" (which would definitely be singular).

Comment: Consider that as a pair. "Supply and demand." You then know that it's singular!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one single concept as the writer says, which consists of supply and demand components. So, it is considered a singular noun.

Thus, it is correct.

Comment: In some contexts it could also be considered a mass noun. ("The high turnover indicated a *great deal of* supply and demand.")